# Find all postgresql and mysql databases on a system

Tags: find, mysql, postgresql

Is there a way to find all postgresql and mysql databases on my system? (Perhaps using the find command).

Comment: Do you search versions like postgresql-8.3, postgresql-8.5, etc. or do you search where the data is stored?

Comment: @userunknown I do search where the data is stored

Answer (score 2):

If the database servers are running, ask them:

```
psql -l

mysql <<< 'show databases'
```

Just searching the filesystem for relational databases is not a trivial task.

Comment: +1 Considering that some relational databases may not even use an FS. :)

Comment: Thanks, but actually I want to know how to search the FS for relational databases.

Answer (score 0):

On my system, the files for postgresql 8.4 are installed in:

```
 sudo ls -l /etc/postgresql/8.4/main/pgdata/base/
 sudo ls -l /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main/base
```

where /etc contains a symbolic link to /var/lib.

You need sudo permissions to watch these directories.